# Filling a dataframe with a dummy value data based on specific col in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a data frame like this:

```
df <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
        member = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 5L),
      q_c3_1 = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A"),
      q_c4_1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L),
      q_c5_1 = c(1900L, 1900L, 1900L, 1900L, 1900L, 1900L, 1900L, 1900L, 1900L,
                 1900L),
      q_c6_1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L),
      q_c7_1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L),
      q_c3_2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
      q_c4_2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
      q_c5_2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
      q_c6_2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
      q_c7_2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
      q_c3_3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
      q_c4_3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
      q_c5_3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
      q_c6_3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
      q_c7_3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
      q_c3_4 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
      q_c4_4 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
      q_c5_4 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
      q_c6_4 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
      q_c7_4 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
      q_c3_5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
      q_c4_5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
      q_c5_5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
      q_c6_5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
      q_c7_5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
)
```

base on member variable, I need to fill corresponding variables with dummy data.For example if member = 2 then `q_c3_2:q_c7_2` should have dummy values --> q_c3 = **some character like "Arne"**, **q_c4 with 1** and **q_c5 with 1900** and **q_c6** and **q_c7** with **0** , if member == 3 then `q_c3_2:q_c7_2` and `q_c3_3:q_c7_3` should have dummy values (same as dummy values as above) and so on. How may i do this and efficiently with tidyverse? Thanks

My desire output shall be like this data frame

```
df2 <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                  member = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 5L),
                  q_c3_1 = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A"),
                  q_c4_1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L),
                  q_c5_1 = c(1900L, 1900L, 1900L, 1900L, 1900L, 1900L, 1900L, 1900L, 1900L,
                             1900L),
                  q_c6_1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L),
                  q_c7_1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L),
                  q_c3_2 = c(NA, NA, "Arne", NA, NA, NA, NA, "Arne", "Arne", "Arne"),
                  q_c4_2 = c(NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L),
                  q_c5_2 = c(NA, NA, 1900L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1900L, 1900L, 1900L),
                  q_c6_2 = c(NA, NA, 0L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0L, 0L, 0L),
                  q_c7_2 = c(NA, NA, 0L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0L, 0L, 0L),
                  q_c3_3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Arne", "Arne", "Arne"),
                  q_c4_3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L),
                  q_c5_3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1900L, 1900L, 1900L),
                  q_c6_3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0L, 0L, 0L),
                  q_c7_3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0L, 0L, 0L),
                  q_c3_4 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Arne", NA, "Arne"),
                  q_c4_4 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L),
                  q_c5_4 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1900L, NA, 1900L),
                  q_c6_4 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0L, NA, 0L),
                  q_c7_4 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0L, NA, 0L),
                  q_c3_5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Arne"),
                  q_c4_5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L),
                  q_c5_5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1900L),
                  q_c6_5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0L),
                  q_c7_5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0L)
)
```

Comment: Not clear about the expected output `should have some values`.  `q_c3_1` already have some values (based on the dput). Can you show the expected

Comment: Sorry, I miss-typed, I meant q_c3_2 , 3, 4 . I edited my question.

Comment: Thanks for showing the expected output.  But, is there any logic in changing the values to `"Arne"`, `1900`, `0`, `1` etc

Comment: Are the dummy variables meaningful in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the assumption that it does not matter what the dummy variables are and using dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
temp <- df %>% 
  melt(id.vars = "member") %>% 
  mutate(compare = as.numeric(gsub("q_c\\d_(\\d)", "\\1", variable))) %>% 
  filter(compare <= member) %>% 
  mutate(value = "dummy",
     compare = NULL) %>%
  unique() %>% 
  spread(variable, value)

df <- df %>% 
  select(member) %>% 
  left_join(., temp, by = "member")
```

Edit: With dummy variables as requested.

```
library(dplyr)
temp <- df %>% 
 melt(id.vars = "member") %>% 
 mutate(compare = as.numeric(gsub("q_c\\d_(\\d)", "\\1", variable)),
        dummy_match = as.numeric(gsub("q_c(\\d)_\\d", "\\1", variable))) %>% 
 filter(compare <= member) %>% 
 mutate(value = case_when(dummy_match == 4 ~ 1,
                          dummy_match == 5 ~ 1900,
                          dummy_match >= 6 ~ 0,
                          T ~ 9999),
        compare = NULL,
        dummy_match = NULL) %>%
 unique() %>% 
 spread(variable, value)

df <- df %>% 
 select(member) %>% 
 left_join(., temp, by = "member")

df[df == 9999] <- "Arne"
```

Comment: Thanks @TomHaddow, your approach fill all cells with "dummy" , I can use case_when and re_fill q_c4 with 1 and q_c5 with 1900 and q_c6 and q_c7 with 0 , but is there any smarter way?

Comment: I will update the answer with how I would do it based on this additional knowledge. I would advice you to include this requirement in your question as this is not clear at all. I don't think my method will be "neat" but it should work.

Comment: Please update "should have some values" and "should have some dummy values" from your original question with the details you provided.